# Problem getting Users from ActiveDirectory [C# in ASP.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryentry

Cannot get the user list from ACtiveDirectory Services when accessed from another system in the same network.

If accessed from where the code is, then we can obtain the userlist, but cannot get it when accessed from other system in the same network.
Any help is utmost appreciated...

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: Please try to title your question properly - currently it bears no relation to your actual question, which is also unclear.

Comment: Hi Venkat - pls make sure you enter as much relevant tags as possible for a quick solution. Also the Question title bears a lot of weight - try to write a good title which summarises your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem maybe a "double hop" related issue. The identity of the calling user cannot be passed on further than the server where the code is. 
One solution is to Bind the call to a user

```
    DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://path", "uname", "password");
    DirectorySearcher dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);
    dsSearch.Filter = "(objectCategory=user)";
```

Comment: +1, i had this issue the other day when I could not select groups from a computer that is not part of the forest. my tip is to always use `LDAP://` and always supply credentials in DirectoryEntry / UserPrincipal

Answer (score 1):

Are you logging in correctly to the DirectoryEntry class?...

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path, domainAndUsername, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article at [csharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jodonnell/ListingADUsers07022005005138AM/ListingADUsers.aspx) about listing user in AD using C#.

This one explains [How To](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) do (almost) anything with AD using C#.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain the scenario - how is your code deployed (I presume it is deployed as an asp.net webservice). If this is a web service then the most probable cause is the account under which asp.net runs doesnt have enough permissions.